# Никак не могу конвертировать JSON в обычный сырой текст (Python)

Tags: python, кодировка, requests

Использую библиотеку `requests`, делаю запрос:

```
req = requests.post(f'example.com/api', headers=headers).text
```

Приходит ответ в формате **JSON**, который имеет вот такой вид:

```
{"description":"\u003Cp\u003E\u003Cb\u003E\u041a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f"}
```

После информация сохраняется в переменной типа str, нужно конвертировать с этой кодировки в обычный человеко-читаемый текст и вывести в консоль.
Если например положить текст в переменную вручную и сделать рэплейс:

```
somevar = '{"description":"\u003Cp\u003E\u003Cb\u003E\u041a\u043e\u043c\u043f\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f"}'.replace('\\', '\\\\')
```

Выводит:

```
<p><b>Компания
```

Но если попробовать так же преобразовать тот текст что приходит и сохраняется в переменной **req** ответом на реквест(он абсолютно такой же) и вывести на эккран:

```
print(req.replace('\\', '\\\\'))
```

То выводится это текст в его сыром виде:

```
{"description":"\\u003Cp\\u003E\\u003Cb\\u003E\\u041a\\u043e\\u043c\\u043f\\u0430\\u043d\\u0438\\u044f"}
```

Я игрался как только можно. И с помощью `codecs.decode()` пытался его декодировать и с помощью `json.loads()` пытался собрать из него словарь и изьять текст по ключу `description` и нашел онлайн конвертер где можно конвертировать JSON в обычный сырой текст и это сработало, но вот только мне нужна реализация :)
Помогите люди добрые. Я обычно редко задаю вопросы, все время гугл да гугл, а тут вообще никак. Пол дня сегодня провозился с этим и толку нет.

**UPDATE:** в общем наверное так надо было сделать изначально, извиняюсь. Привожу полный исходный текст, дабы максимально со своей стороны прояснить ситуацию для более опытных товарищей желающим помочь
Можно воспроизвести это и увидеть полноценный JSON ответ, в общем все то, что есть у меня в сорце

```
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://www.work.ua/ru/jobs/2429327/'

    headers = {
        'Authority':'www.work.ua',
        'Method':'POST',
        'Scheme':'https',
        'Accept':'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language':'ru-UA,ru-RU;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.6',
        'Content-Length':'0',
        'Dnt':'1',
        'Origin':'https://www.work.ua',
        'Referer':f'{url}',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest':'empty',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode':'cors',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site':'same - origin',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36',
        'X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'
    }

    req = requests.post(f'{url}ajax/get-jobs-data/', headers=headers).text
    
    print(req)
```

Просто нужно как то ответ конвертировать в человеко-читаемый вид, но у меня все никак не выходит.

Comment: `json.loads` прекрасно работает. Но раз уж Вы пользуетесь `requests`, то можно просто `requests.post(...).json()`.

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Всё [работает](https://ideone.com/gRW5kk).[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @nomnoms12 я использую `requests.post(...).json()` и пытаюсь извлечь по ключу description содержимое, но получаю ошибку 
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2212' in position 805: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: @Кирилл Малышев: да, если туда вручную положить данные то все работает. Но если я пытаюсь вывести ответ который мне приходит в формате JSON с реквеста, то выводится все в сыром виде. В этом собственно и вся соль данного вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем большое спасибо за то, что попытались помочь. Я точно не понял как это работает, но видимо проблемы с кодировкой в windows или что то типа этого.

Я пробежался еще по аналогичным темам и методом научного тыка попробовал использовать вот такого рода фичу и это сработало, о чудо! Вывелся человекочитаемый текст.

```
req = requests.post(f'{url}ajax/get-jobs-data/', headers=headers).json()
print(req['description'].encode('cp1251', errors='replace').decode('cp1251'))
```

Если кто то может найти этому объяснение или просто дополнить решение более "элегантным" способом, то я был бы только рад.

Comment: Что у выводит если сделать `print(repr(req))`?

Comment: @insolor если в это время в переменной req лежат данные в формате простого текста, то выводит то же самое, только уже с двойным слэшем
Вот это:` \\u003Cp\\u003E\\u003Cb\\u003E\\u041a\\ `
Почему то не выделяется, блин)

Comment: Ну значит у вас все нормально с json, просто консоль не может отображать некоторые символы юникода. Второй строкой ответа вы просто убираете такие символы из строки. \u2212 - это [юникодный знак минус](https://unicode-table.com/ru/2212/). Можно тупо делать в строке `x.replace('\u2212', '-')`. Если записывать текст в файл в utf-8, а не выводить на консоль, то никаких дополнительных манипуляций не нужно будет.

Comment: @insolor да, спасибо, это так же работает)

Answer (score 1):

Собственно все, что нужно, вам уже сказали в комментариях. Все работает, если заменить атрибут `text` на метод `json()`. То есть предпоследняя строка должна выглядеть вот так:

```py
req = requests.post(f'{url}ajax/get-jobs-data/', headers=headers).json()
```

Результат (вывод приведен не полностью):

```py
{'description': '<p><b>Компания ***, официальный партнер **** в\xa0Украине, проводит набор ...'}
```

Обращу только внимание на то, что в ответе вы получаете сырую html-разметку с большим числом экранированных символов.

Comment: спасибо, но это все ровно в моем случае не помогло. Я поймал вот такую ошибку: 
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2212' in position 867: character maps to <undefined>`
Видимо это была какая то более специфическая проблема связаная с кодировкой в виндовс или еще с чем то, точно не понял пока что. Но решение которое я запостил ниже - сработало. Надеюсь тем, кто с этим так же столкнется - какое то из предложенных решений так же поможет, как помогло и мне.